# What is a word for implying someone else is wrong?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms, vocabulary

For instance, if someone says to you, "I like cake," and you reply, "I like to take care of my body," your response is a passive-aggressive way of implying that they don't like to take care of their body because they eat cake.

I'm looking for an adjective to describe this type of response, something akin to passive-aggressive but more specific to the situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Haughty](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/haughty#Adjective)* (“Conveying in demeanour the assumption of superiority; disdainful, supercilious”) and   *[supercilious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supercilious#Adjective)* (“Arrogantly superior; showing contemptuous indifference; haughty”) seem relevant, along with some of the other terms in those definitions (eg *[arrogant](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arrogant#Adjective)*, *[disdainful](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disdainful)*, and *[contemptuous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contemptuous)*) along with related words or phrases like *[holier-than-thou](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/holier-than-thou)*, *[sanctimonious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sanctimonious)*, *[hoity-toity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hoity-toity)*, and *[stuck up](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stuck_up#Adjective)*.

Comment: All appropriate - and let's add "rude"!

Comment: This helped me think of one that is as close as I can find:  definition 1b of [sententious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sententious).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *[snarky](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/snarky)*

> said in a way that is intended to make someone feel stupid or bad

Comment: You could call *I like to take care of my body* a *snark*.

Answer (score 1):

Synonyms of http://thesaurus.com/browse/critical:

disparaging, belittling, biting, censorious, condemning, cutting, saracastic, scolding seem to be especially on point.

Comment: Can you add a def for *saracastic*?

Comment: 'Censorious' is particularly good here as it picks up the indirectness of the rebuke.

Answer (score 1):

caustic ("[a caustic remark criticizes someone in a way that is unkind but often cleverly humorous](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/caustic)")